# Visual Studio 2017 Installer create ProgramData folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a Setup project in Visual Studio 2017 where I need to create a custom folder in ProgramData folder.

When I right-click on File System of Setup Project I get this options:

[image]

But I can't find `ProgramData` option or similar.

> Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found it.

You have to manually set the Directory to be:

```
[CommonAppDataFolder]
```